# Is it possible to use RAID-Z/Z2 and iSCSI on FreeNAS 8

Tags: raid, iscsi, truenas, raidz

I am trying to configure FreeNas 8 to expose an RAID-Z or RAID-Z2 volume via iSCSI.  I have had limited success. If I delete the RAID-Z volume and simply expose a "physical" disk in the iSCSI setup then everything works no problem.  I have 4 * 2TB disks that I wanted to add to the RAID-Z volume.

With the amount of success I'm starting to think that maybe it's not possible to do this (or least not possible from the web GUI). Has anyone else done this before? Is it possible? Is there a trick I haven't discovered?

Comment: If something isn't supported in the GUI, then it is available at the command line.  I've exported a RAID-Z volume that wasn't formatted as ZFS this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can't do an `Auto` size when you create the extent. When I specified a size everything worked as expected.  Turning on the log on the web was extremely helpful!